# Simpler Way to Write a sum of factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I have a fairly simple question. I was wondering if there is a simpler way to write the following: $$\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!}$$

So for example, given $n=4$ and $x=3$, we would have $$1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5+2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6+3\cdot 4\cdot 5\cdot 6\cdot 7=3360$$

Is there a simpler way to write this or do this calculation?

**Edit:** Ok I have simplified the sum above to the following: $$\frac{x(n+x+1)!}{(n+2)(x!)}$$

Can I simplify this further?

Comment: The only simplification I can think of is dividing $x$ in the numerator into the denominator to get $\frac{(n+x+1)!}{(n+2) Γ(x)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!}=\frac{1}{n+2}\left(\frac{(k+n+2)!}{k!}-\frac{(k+n+1)!}{(k-1)!}\right)$$

Therefore, evaluating the telescoping sum is trivial and yields

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{x-1}\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!}&=(n+1)!+\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!}\\\\
&=(n+1)!+\frac{1}{n+2}\left(\frac{(x+n+1)!}{(x-1)!}-\frac{(n+2)!}{1!}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n+2}\frac{(x+n+1)!}{(x-1)!}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n+2}\prod_{\ell =0}^{n+1}(x+\ell)\\\\
&=(n+1)!\binom{x+n+1}{x-1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well, if we are to believe WolframAlpha, then yes there is:

$$\sum_{k=1}^x\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!}= \frac{(x+1)(n+x+2)!-(n+2)!(x+1)!}{(n+2)(x+1)!}$$

Expect an edit of me trying to prove that...

Comment: Yes, but with this one would have to calculate more factorials. So it wouldn't be ideal to use this formula

Comment: @user328951 More than calculating the sum by hand? I mean, as you scale up $x$ the RHS becomes much easier to calculate. But I sorta see what you mean...let me try to think of a perhaps simpler way of writing it.

Comment: @user328951 That is untrue.  The left-hand side requires a summation of the ratio of two factorials.  So, one computes $x \times 2$ terms with factorials.  The right-hand side only requires computation of $4$ factorial terms.

Comment: @Αδριανός Can you see my edit?

Comment: @Dr.MV Can  you see my edit?

Comment: @user328951 Yes I can see your edit, but I am a bit skeptical that a sum to $x-1$ is independent of $x$...

Comment: @Αδριανός Yeah. I just replaced x with k.

Comment: @Dr.MV I edited.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=0}^{x-1} \dfrac{(n+k+1)!}{k!} = \dfrac{x (n+x+1)!}{(n+2) x!} $$

Comment: That's what I have in my edit(. I want to simplify that further.

Comment: Other than $x/x! = 1/(x-1)!$, you could use the Pochhammer function.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, but not sure it is simpler:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^x \frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!} = \sum_{k=1}^x \binom{n+k+1}{k} (n+1)!
$$

Comment: Yeah. I don't think that's simpler. Can you think of anything different?

Comment: Can you work off of my edit?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly a commentary to the answers of Αδριανός and Robert Israel: using Gosper's algorithm (`AntiDifference((n+k+1)!/k!,k)` in Maxima):
$$
\frac{(n+k+1)!}{k!} = 
{{(n+k+2)!}\over{k!(n+2)}} -
{{(n+k+1)!}\over{(k-1)!(n+2)}}
$$and the sum telescopes.